# Slides not rendering using swiper.js when written dynamically

Tags: javascript, carousel

Using swiper.js carousel with the slides being written dynamically. Inspecting the HTML, the code for the slides is there. The carousel slides are not rendering correctly and they disappear when I click on the arrows.

The content of the carousel:

```
function addLibraryCourses(libidx) {     

    var dynamiccontainer = $('.dynamic-library-container');
    dynamiccontainer.find('.spinner').remove();                            

    var pushcontainer = pushlibs[libidx];
    var dynamiccontainerclassname = 'dynamiccontainer_' + libidx;
    var dynamicSwipeName = 'dynamicSwipeName' + libidx;
    var outer = $('<div class="dynamiccontainer-item gray-bg" />')
        .append(
            $('<div class="text-header" />')
                .append(
                    $('<div class="leftside" />').html(pushcontainer.lefttext)
                )
                .append(
                    $('<div class="rightside" />')    
                        .attr('libraryid', pushcontainer.libraryid)   
                        .click(library_click)                                                     
                        .html(pushcontainer.righttext)                                                
                )
        )
        .append(
            $('<div class="swiper-container '+ dynamicSwipeName +'"><div class="' + dynamiccontainerclassname + ' course-list-container course-list-container-sm swiper-wrapper" /><div class="swiper-button-next"></div><div class="swiper-button-prev"></div></div>')
        );                                                    
        dynamiccontainer.append(outer);
        var courselistcontainer = $('.' + dynamiccontainerclassname);
        var swipeContainer = $('.' + dynamicSwipeName);
        addPlaylistToContainer(courselistcontainer, pushcontainer.courses, true); //global 

        var swipeContainer = new Swiper(swipeContainer, {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            spaceBetween: 0, 
            loop: true
        });
    _gettingDynamicContainers = false;
    getAndBuildLowerUI(); // get next
    /* end build dynamic containers */
};
```

Partial Code page code:

```
<div class="swiper-container dynamicSwipeName0 swiper-container-horizontal">
    <div class="dynamiccontainer_0 course-list-container course-list-container-sm swiper-wrapper" style="transform: translate3d(-851px, 0px, 0px); transition-duration: 0ms;">
       <div class="list-item playable swiper-slide carouselItem swiper-slide-duplicate" courseid="2461" data-swiper-slide-index="7" style="width: 283.667px;">
          <div class="cover-art">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/images.learnsmartnow.com/LMS/CourseImagesHD/default.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="progress">
            <img src="/Content/css/imported/global/course-completion-empty.png" title="Not Started 0%." alt="Not Started 0%.">
          </div>
          <div class="details">
            <div class="title" courseid="2461">Hacker: Cloud Computing-Attacks</div>
            <div class="list-view-play-button" style="display: none;"><img alt="play" title="play" style="cursor: pointer;" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/btnPlay.png" courseid="2461">                    
          </div>
          <div class="info">33m | 2 Lessons</div>
          <div class="rating"><div class="stars-container"><img class="star star-full" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/rating-star-full.png"><img class="star star-full" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/rating-star-full.png"><img class="star star-full" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/rating-star-full.png"><img class="star star-half" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/rating-star-half.png"><img class="star star-empty" src="https://media-public.learnsmartsystems.com/LMS2/siteicons/rating-star-empty.png"></div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

...
[image: carousel screenshot]

Any ideas how to get the carousel to render correctly?

Comment: check the developer console. image might not be available